# How to use small numbers for junction names in sumo?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to apply shortest path algorithm to vehicles in veins. 
In my algorithm i am using junctions and edges from **map.net.xml**, but sumo gives large numbers to junction and edge names.
Is there any option to start numbers in map from 0?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you create your network. You can either write your own network inputs [from SUMO's XML](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/PlainXML) files then you are free to choose whichever ids you want.
If you use OpenStreetMap (which is probably the case if you have large numbers as ids) you can apply a prefix to edge and node ids using the `--prefix` option to make them non-numeric and then in a second run the --numerical-ids option. Please note that this will change the ids for the edges as well. So the process is:

```
netconvert --prefix a --osm-files osm.xml -o tmp.net.xml
netconvert --numerical-ids -s tmp.net.xml -o final.net.xml
```